# The equivalent conditions for a subset of a field being a subspace

Tags: field-theory

Suppose S is a subset of F2. Show that S is a subspace of F2 if and only if 0 ∈ S and S is closed under addition.

My question is that why we only need to show that it is closed under addition without showing it is closed under multiplication?

Comment: It looks like that’s what you are being asked to show

Comment: It's hard to answer your question, because your statement is missing any explanation of your notation and terminology. I would hate to guess wrongly at what they mean. What is F2? What is the definition of a "subspace of F2"?

Comment: F2 is a field , and "subspace of F2" just simply means "subspace of a field which only contain 0 and 1"

Comment: Is “F2” the field with two elements? Then there are only four subsets in all, and only $\{0,1\}$ and $\{0\}$ are subspaces. It seems very unlikely to me that you have quoted the question correctly, since it seems almost vacuous.